# Persistent Makefile Variables

Tags: makefile

I want my Makefile to be invoked like this:

```
make x11 oss bin
```

which should result in compiling the files: `main.c x11.c oss.c` and link them into one executable file `bin`.

Another way to invoke it would be:

```
make x11 alsa bin
```

which should do the same thing but with `main.c x11.c alsa.c`

This is my Makefile:

```
bin: $(OBJ) main.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) main.o $(LDLIBS)
x11:
    set OBJ += bsd.o
oss:
    set OBJ += oss.o
alsa:
    set OBJ += alsa.o
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

but it seems that the contents of the OBJ variable isn't persistent throughout the recipes. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is simply not the way standard makefiles are invoked (although it can be kludged). Wouldn't it be better to write a script called, say, `create`, which is invoked your way and which calls Make conventionally?

Comment: I'm a sort of a minimalist, up to the point where I think a solution needing only one file is better than one that needs two and wouldn't mind if it isn't how things are normally done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJ *is* persistent, but you have another problem:

- The Makefile first is completely parsed by make. And thus $OBJ still is unset/empty in this stage. Therefore, the bin target only gets `main.o` as dependency since all variables are replaced with their value in this stage.
- Next, OBJ is being updated with its content using the given targets on the command line. But OBJ is not used anymore for the bin target, since make is finihed building the dependencies already. (Makefile normally is not parsed a second time)

The trick is to have the OBJ variable filled *before* the parsing. A simple solution is to call the Makefile using:

```
make "OBJ=x11 oss" bin
```

and modify the Makefile a bit to have the `.o`-part added (or just add them to the make command):

```
bin: $(patsubst %,%.o,$(OBJ)) main.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) main.o $(LDLIBS)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

**Note**: I said 'Makefile normally is not parsed a second time'. It *is* possible to recursively use the Makefile multiple times. This is very complicated and probably not required for 99% of all cases. An example of such 'make abuse' is the [OpenWRT buildsystem](https://dev.openwrt.org). [trunk/Makefile](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/Makefile) is an example of a Makefile is is called multiple times by itself.

Answer (score 0):

*This is somewhat of a hack.*

Add this like to the top of your Makefile:

```
OBJ := $(filter-out bin,${MAKECMDGOALS})
```

Now when you type `make x11 oss bin` make parses this:

```
OBJ := x11 oss
```

and for `make x11 alsa bin` it will see

```
OBJ := x11 alsa
```

You will probably have to remove the shell commands for *x11* et. al. as `set OBJ += bsd.o` is not valid shell.